# I am trying to start up the server for rails and I get the following error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

/Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:99:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError) from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in` load'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in `data' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in` fetch'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in `public_path' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in` public_output_path'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in `public_manifest_path' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in` load'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in `refresh' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:47:in` bootstrap'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in `bootstrap' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:41:in` block in class:Engine'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in` run'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in` block in tsort_each'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in` each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in` each'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in` each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in` tsort_each'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in` initialize!'
from /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` require'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in` register'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in` require'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in` block in require'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in` require'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative' from config.ru:3:in` block in '
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in` new_from_string'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in` parse_file'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in` app'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in` log_to_stdout'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in` block in perform'
from internal:kernel:90:in `tap' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in` perform'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in` invoke_command'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in` perform'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in` '
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in` require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require' from /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/bin/rails:5:in` <top (required)>'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in` call'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in` run'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in` load'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>' from <internal:/Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from internal:/Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require' from /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/bin/spring:10:in` block in <top (required)>'
from internal:kernel:90:in `tap' from /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/bin/spring:7:in` <top (required)>'
from bin/rails:2:in `load' from bin/rails:2:in` '
/Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:96:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/config/webpacker.yml (Errno::ENOENT) from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:96:in` read'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:96:in `load' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:92:in` data'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:88:in `fetch' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:43:in` public_path'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:47:in `public_output_path' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:51:in` public_manifest_path'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:83:in `load' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/manifest.rb:18:in` refresh'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/commands.rb:47:in `bootstrap' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker.rb:35:in` bootstrap'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/webpacker-5.2.1/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:41:in `block in <class:Engine>' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in` instance_exec'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in` block in run_initializers'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in` block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in` block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in` call'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in` tsort_each'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in` run_initializers'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!' from /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/config/environment.rb:5:in` '
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in` require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in` require'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in` load_dependency'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in` require_relative'
from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in` eval'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in` load_file'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in` build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in` wrapped_app'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in` start'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform' from <internal:kernel>:90:in` tap'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in` run'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in` dispatch'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in` invoke'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in` require'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in` register'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in` require'
from /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in` load'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in` call'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in` <top (required)>'
from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load' from /Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in` <top (required)>'
from internal:/Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require' from <internal:/Users/griselpaiz/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in` require'
from /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>' from <internal:kernel>:90:in` tap'
from /Users/griselpaiz/test_app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>' from bin/rails:2:in` load'
from bin/rails:2:in `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message clearly mentions what the issue is and offers the solution as well.

> Webpacker configuration file not found `/Users/griselpaiz/test_app/config/webpacker.yml.`

Run `rails webpacker:install` to configure Webpacker and you should be good to go.